# Use ES6 arrow function as AJAX callback handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In a [Vue lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks), I have the following AJAX call

```
created: function () {

  axios.get(`/list-suppliers/${this.newAwardNdc}`).then(function (response) {
    this.supplierCount = _.uniqBy(response.data, 'groupNumber').length;
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Is it possible to handle the result of the AJAX call with an arrow function instead? I tried the following

```
created: function () {

  axios.get(`/list-suppliers/${this.newAwardNdc}`).then(response => {
    this.supplierCount = _.uniqBy(response.data, 'groupNumber').length;
  });
}
```

But it fails because `this` is not bound correctly.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe try `created() {}` instead of `created: function(){}` then this won't point to the function but the vue instance instead.

Comment: It should behave the same way, how is `created` called maybe you bound it in one case and didn't in the other?

Comment: With arrow functions, the this refers the function itself.

Comment: created:  -- this seems like a method on an object and inside it you're making an API call. The object which has this property, you should directly use that object inside arrow function. Lets say the object name is X. So x.supplierCount should be used inside it.

Comment: The arrow functions look fine. How did you come to the conclusion that `this` is causing the issue? What error are you getting on browser console. Please attach an error stack along with questions moving forward.

Comment: @SagarAgrawal: `this` does not refer to the function.

Comment: There is no situation where the first example would work differently than the second example.

Comment: Then where does this refer to if not function ?

Comment: @SagarAgrawal to the parent scope.

Comment: @SagarAgrawal: In 99% of all cases the value of `this` depends on *how* a function is called. E.g. if it's a property of an object and called as `obj.method()` then `this` refers to `obj`. If you call a function with `.call`, e.g. `func.call(foo)`, then `this` refers to `foo`. If you call a function normally, `func()`, `this` is either `undefined` or refers to the global object. For `this` to refer to the function itself, the function would have to be called as `func.call(func)` which is not something people usually do.

Comment: @FelixKling I know that part but that’s applicable to normal functions. I thought “this” behaves differently in case of arrow functions.

Comment: @SagarAgrawal: Arrow functions simply resolve `this` lexically like any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give some additional context, since the [documentation you've linked](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) alongside the promise handler arrow function works perfectly fine.

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log(this.a, this.supplierCount);
    axios.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/xva5k").then(response => {
      this.supplierCount = _.uniqBy(response.data, 'groupNumber').length;
      console.log(this.a, this.supplierCount);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```